# Optimizing a given code snippet in Python

Tags: python, optimization, nested-loops

I have a code snippet written in Python which performs the required task, however it is very time consuming since it uses 3 nested for-loops, I am not able to optimize it so that it can run faster so I'm seeking for any help. Here is the code snippet:

```
def calculate_cost_volume(left_image_ct, right_image_ct, max_disparity, left=True):
    h, w = left_image_ct.shape
    cost_volume = np.zeros((max_disparity, h, w))

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            for d in range(max_disparity):
                x_right = j - d
                if not left:
                    x_right = j + d
                if x_right < 0 or x_right >= w:
                    cost_volume[d, i, j] = float('inf')
                    continue
                binary_str = bin(left_image_ct[i, j] ^ right_image_ct[i, x_right])
                cost_volume[d, i, j] = binary_str.count('1')

    return cost_volume
```

I tried to get help from ChatGPT but he wasn't able to help me and produced many errors, I know that this isn't something that worth saying but I'm not really that good in Python so I don't really know what advanced methods there are out there.

Comment: post sample constructors/initializers for  `left_image_ct, right_image_ct` and actual `max_disparity` value

Comment: In general you should avoid looping over numpy arrays explicitly. Use `np.where()` to filter, and then do the calculation there.

Comment: Actually, they represent `left_image_ct` and `right_image_ct` represent census transform for both images and `max_disparity` represents maximum disparity. I don't think it's crucial to know these parameters right? if it is I can provide information in the post.

Comment: @Barmar The code is actually not really long and as I said I don't really know much about Python, like I know what np.where is but I'm not willing to miss things up, can you write a code with np.where showing your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a numpy expert, I can just explain general principles.

Comment: @StrawUser, without sample testable `left_image_ct, right_image_ct`  I can't check that "*it is very time consuming*". So it's up to you

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I uploaded the required files to a link since they are huge matrices of size 11MB each. Please note that it is uploaded as .txt files with delimiter=','. Please find the files here: https://file.io/66EYDmyiATsq

Comment: @StrawUser, ok, and what's actual `max_disparity` value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry for not mentioning that, it's 77.

Comment: @StrawUser, the above code throws error `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types` on line `binary_str = bin(left_image_ct[i, j] ^ right_image_ct[i, x_right])`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tried running the code multiple times and it works perfectly fine, interesting. Actually, you can run the code for any 2D `left_image_ct` and `right_image_ct` matrices and for max_disp=77. I don't really know why the error you mentioned occured.

Comment: @StrawUser, I'm running it exactly on those 2 numpy matrices from the file you've shared. `left_image_ct.shape` is `(436, 1024)`

Comment: @StrawUser, what's your `left_image_ct.dtype` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest when debugging I get this: left_image_ct = {ndarray: (436, 1024)}

Comment: It would be extraordinarily helpful (for us and then you) if you could update your post with a small example of one of your images, **NOT** some 11MB monster, just edit or construct a 5x5 matrix of the data you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the *last* thing you want to do with `numpy` matrices is iterate over them when you should be letting `numpy` do the heavy lifting all at once with vectorized operations.

You appear to be right-shifting one matrix and computing the element-wise XOR.  That can be done in vectorized format fairly easily.

You should be doing something like this example below.  As they say in the textbooks, "It is left as an exercise for the interested reader to complete the exercise" which would be capturing this output in the format you want and filling in the "N/A" or "inf" values for the overlap offsets.

##### Code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).reshape((3,3))
B = np.array([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]).reshape((3,3))

print("A:")
print(A)
print("B:")
print(B)
print()
# d is your "disparity" value...
for d in range(3):
    D = A[:, d:] ^ B[:, :3-d]
    print(D)
```

##### Output:

```
A:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
B:
[[9 8 7]
 [6 5 4]
 [3 2 1]]

[[ 8 10  4]
 [ 2  0  2]
 [ 4 10  8]]
[[11 11]
 [ 3  3]
 [11 11]]
[[10]
 [ 0]
 [10]]
```